# Does ORMLITE support SQL EXISTS?

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I am trying to query a table as follows

```
select * from client c
    where EXISTS (select * from visit v where c._id = v.client_id)
```

Can i do this with ORMLITE?

Comment: Did my answer help?  I'd appreciate it if you accept it if it did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.  [`Where.exists()`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/Where.html#exists%28com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder%29) has been supported my [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) for some time.  Here are the [meager docs on exists](http://ormlite.com/docs/exists).

You would do something like the following:

```
QueryBuilder<Visit, Integer> visitQb = visitDao.queryBuilder();
visitQb.where().eq(Visit.CLIENT_ID_FIELD, client.getId());
QueryBuilder<Client, Integer> clientQb = clientDao.queryBuilder();
clientQb.where().exists(visitQb);
List<Client> results = clientQb.query();
```

Comment: How would you use exists in ORMLite if you wanted to do a "select *"? Because (correct me if i'm wrong) but the example expects that client id is known?

Comment: I don't understand the question @JasperSiepkes.  Please create your own question with more details and post the link.

Comment: How would you do a query like `WHERE visit.clientId = client.id` without first querying all client ids? In your example you're using `client.getId()` but don't want to specify a single value. I think this is also @JasperSiepkes' question.