# How to match by id when using ORMLite Where Not Exists

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm building my query using the advice from [Does ORMLITE support SQL EXISTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294586/does-ormlite-support-sql-exists)

```
public List<Crag> getAllCragsWithLocation() {
    QueryBuilder<Crag, Integer> cragQueryBuilder = _helper.getCragDao().queryBuilder();
    QueryBuilder<CragLocation, Integer> cragLocationQueryBuilder = _helper.getCragLocationDao().queryBuilder();
        try {
            cragLocationQueryBuilder.where().eq("locationType", 0);
            cragQueryBuilder.where().exists(cragLocationQueryBuilder);
            return cragQueryBuilder.query();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
            return new ArrayList<Crag>();
        } 
}
```

This returns all crags regardless of if they have a cragLocation so long as there are any cragLocation with a locationType of 0. Which is understandable...

In the example linked above...

```
QueryBuilder<Visit, Integer> visitQb = visitDao.queryBuilder();
visitQb.where().eq(Visit.CLIENT_ID_FIELD, client.getId());
QueryBuilder<Client, Integer> clientQb = clientDao.queryBuilder();
clientQb.where().exists(visitQb);
List<Client> results = clientQb.query();
```

I guess the query is linking to the id of a specific client or perhaps more clearly

```
select * from client c
    where EXISTS (select * from visit v where c._id = v.client_id)
```

in my case

```
select * from Crag c
    where EXISTS (select * from CragLocation cl where c.id = cl.crag_id)
```

So my final query would be:

```
select * from Crag c
    where EXISTS (select * from CragLocation cl where c.id = cl.crag_id and cl.location_type = 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you want to be using [SQL EXISTS](http://sqltutorials.blogspot.com/2007/06/sql-exists.html) here.  The query that [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) is going to generate does *not* include any special `WHERE` clause -- it's not that smart.

```
cragLocationQueryBuilder.where().eq("locationType", 0);
cragQueryBuilder.where().exists(cragLocationQueryBuilder);
```

This query means that if the there are *any* locations where `locationType == 0` then it will return *all* of the `Crag` entries.

I would recommend that you use the [`where().in(QueryBuilder)` method](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/Where.html#in%28java.lang.String,%20com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder%29).  This way you can return the crags that have a location whose type is 0.

```
cragLocationQueryBuilder.selectColumns("crag_id).where().eq("locationType", 0);
cragQueryBuilder.where().in("id", cragLocationQueryBuilder);
```

This will generate a SQL query something like:

```
select * from Crag
    where id IN (select crag_id from CragLocation cl.location_type = 0)
```