# Using EXISTS with ORMLite

Tags: android, ormlite

I am trying to query a table as follows

```
SELECT * from PROGRAMME p
     where EXISTS (select * from LOT lot where p.id = lot.PROGRAMME_ID and ...)
```

I used this link but that does not solve my problem
[Does ORMLITE support SQL EXISTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294586/does-ormlite-support-sql-exists)

In this case how do I get the id of the parent table (Programme Table)
when I call:

```
QueryBuilder<Visit, Integer> lotQb = lotDao.queryBuilder();
lotQb.where().eq(LOT.ROGRAMME_ID, ?);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this case how do I get the id of the parent table (Programme Table) when I call:

So if I understand the question, you can use the `ColumnArg` type.  Here are the docs on the subject:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/column-arg

So you would do something like:

```
 QueryBuilder<Visit, Integer> lotQb = lotDao.queryBuilder();
 lotQb.where().eq(LOT.ROGRAMME_ID, new ColumnArg("PROGRAMME", "id"));
```